# T-SQL Query to Calculate Out Of Stock

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The end goal is to calculate Adjusted Daily Volume for new product.

First I need to know when an item is out of stock, that is what is killing me.

```
TransaDate  ItemCode    TransQty    OnHandBefore    OnHandAfter
1/1/2016    xyz-125       -5              20               15
1/4/2016    xyz-126       -4              15               11
1/7/2016    xyz-127       -2              11                9
1/8/2016    xyz-128       -6               9                3
1/8/2016    xyz-129       -3               3                0
1/13/2016   xyz-130       20               0               20
1/13/2016   xyz-131       -4              20               16
1/13/2016   xyz-132      -10              16                6
1/18/2016   xyz-133       -6               6                0
1/23/2016   xyz-134        5               0                5
1/26/2016   xyz-135       -5               5                0
1/28/2016   xyz-136       20               0               20
1/28/2016   xyz-137       -4              20               16
```

Anytime an OnHandAfter is zero I want to consider the item out of stock that entire day. Ideally I would ignore days where there is 0 Before or After since those are both partial sales. But the important, and hard part for me, is the days after an item goes out of stock. There are no entries so I can't do a straight join. So in the above example the item is out of stock on the 26th and on the 27th, even though the 27th isn't listed. In total this example shows Jan 8,9,10,11,12,13 as out of stock, then we receive 20 into stock, then Jan 18,19,20,21,22,23,26,27,28 are also out of stock.

Total Sold: 49
Average Daily Volume: 49/31 = 1.58
Days Out-Of-Stock: 15
Adjusted Daily Volume: 49/(31-15) = 3.06

Since no records are made for days with no sales I think I need to create a derived table (or something like that) that contains all the dates in the range. To make it more complicate the date range will be dynamic for each item, I need to know how many are sold in the first 30 days the item went live on our site. So the start date needs to be dynamic for each item.

The other main table is the item table. I would show what I have so far but it would be know help at all. I am at a complete loss as to the best way to structure this.

Here is my best, but sadly incomplete and sorry attempt, at showing what I want and how I think I might get to it.

```
With CTE_FirstSaleDate as 
(
 SELECT MIN(TransDate) as FirstSoldOn FROM InventoryTransaction
), 
WITH CTE_AllDatesTable
AS
(
  SELECT FirstSoldOn AS [date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
  FROM CTE_DatesTable
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) < DATEADD(dd, 30, FirstSoldOn)
),
CTE_OOS as
(
SELECT TOP 1 i.ItemCode, it.TransactionDate
FROM InventoryTransaction it
WHERE ( it.OnHandAfter = 0 )
ORDER BY it.TransactionDate DESC
)
Select i.ItemCode, DaysCount, DaysOOSCount, AvgDlyVol, AdjDlyVol 
From Items i
Join InventoryTransaction...
```

Any help regarding how I can get a bunch of tables, dynamic dates that aren't in tables and all this other stuff together will be greatly appreciated. Sure it would be awesome if there is one magical script but this will be run once per month so breaking it down is fine.

Comment: Are you looking to get the actual dates that something is out of stock, or just the number of days?

Comment: Just the number days. Partly to calculate the adjusted daily volume but also to see the % of time something is out of stock. Like the example data doesn't look too bad until you dig into it and realize it is almost out of stock 50% of the time.

Comment: Is ItemCode a unique identifier for each transaction and allocated in order?

Comment: ItemCode is unique in Item table, not in the InventoryTransaction table. There are more columns in InventoryTransaction, TransactionID

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of time while thinking.  TransactionID is a unique field in InventoryTransaction but ItemCode is not. ItemCodes are ordered based on when they were added to cart. I hope that answers the question.

Comment: With a [Calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20150512230546/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html) this kind of queries become easy.

Comment: @user3096720 how do I know that Item Code xyz-137 is for the same item as Item Code xyz-125?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get the number of days out of stock:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TransaDate) as RN
    FROM InventoryTransaction
)
SELECT c1.TransaDate, c2.TransaDate, DATEDIFF(d, c1.TransaDate, c2.TransaDate) As NumDays
FROM CTE C1
INNER JOIN CTE C2
    ON C1.RN = C2.RN - 1
WHERE C1.OnHandAfter = 0 AND C2.OnHAndBefore = 0
```

> EDIT

If I assume that ItemCode is the thing column that links all transactions for a particular Item (this doesn't look right from your sample) then this would query would work:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By ItemCode ORDER BY TransaDate) as RN
    FROM InventoryTransaction
)
SELECT c1.TransaDate, c2.TransaDate, 
       DATEDIFF(d, c1.TransaDate, COALESCE(c2.TransaDate, c1.TransaDate)) As NumDays
FROM CTE C1
LEFT JOIN CTE C2
    ON C1.RN = C2.RN - 1 AND C1.ItemCode = C2.ItemCode
WHERE C1.OnHandAfter = 0 AND C2.OnHAndBefore = 0
```

Comment: This is working. I have tested a few date ranges and different items and the only problem I have run into is when the item goes out of stock at the end of the date range.  For example, if my date range is 03/01 - 03/31 and the item goes out of stock on 03/30 then the result shows  c1.TransDate = 2016-03-30, c2.TransDate = 2013-07-17 and NumDays = -987. I am not sure how 2013-07-17 next found row.   Maybe I can do a simple IF, if NumDays is < 0 then EndDate - C2.TransDate.

Comment: @user3096720 if you can add some more data to your question to show this issue that would help. If you have more than 1 item then your join should also include this, I couldn't see from your sample data what the join should use as your itemcode doesn't seem to identify an item.

Comment: The second version you provided rules! I am going to have to really study this one, Self-joining partitioned CTE aren't easy for me to visualize or understand but based on the results I need to work with them more. The first version you provided worked but took about 2 minutes to run. The second version ran in under a second. Amazing! I assume it is the Partition By that speeds thing up, unless it is the left join being faster than inner join.  Thank you Steve, thank you for this new, shiny educational toy for me to play with. I am sincerely giddy right now!